# css - how to make the div have specific aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my current layout.

[image]

This is what I want to make:
[image]

1.the width and height of the outer container should have above aspect ratio
2.the content area should have same aspect ratio

App.js (I am using Bootstrap so no css file is involved for now)

```
      <div class="border p-3 m-2 bg-info" style={{ width: "400px" }}>
        <div class="p-2 bg-light">
          <div class="border p-1 border-warning" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <div
              class="card text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between bg-light border border-warning"
              style={{ height: "100%" }}
            >
              <div class="card-body" style={{ flexGrow: 2 }}></div>
              <div class="card-footer text-white p-4 border-top border-warning">
                <span class="bg-danger fs-3">123</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-monad-50lwd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `p-4` from `<div clas="card-footer">`, then add `aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;` in class `.card-body`